# Error al depurar en Visual Code: No se puede abrir 'libgcc2.c'

Tags: c++, vscode

Al depurar paso a paso por instrucciones (F11) en Visual Studio Code todo va bien, pero cuando llego a la línea 72 aproximadamente me salta el siguiente error:

> No se puede abrir 'libgcc2.c': No se puede leer el archivo (Error:
>   Archivo no encontrado
>   (\home\keith\src\mingw\gcc-build\gcc-6.3.0-mingw32-cross-native\mingw32\libgcc......\src\gcc-6.3.0\libgcc\libgcc2.c)).

El código compila correctamente, y si lo depuro pero no paso a paso por instrucciones, termina correctamente.

```
void simplificarFraccion(long long numerador, unsigned long long denominador){ //Simplifica todo lo posible una fracción.
    for(long long divisor=2; //Ambos siempre tendrán al 1 como divisor común, por eso divisor se inicializa como 2
    divisor <= abs(numerador) && denominador; //El mayor divisor de un numero es el mismo número. Positivos: menor o igual. Negativos: mayor o igual. Por eso abs().
    divisor++){

        /*'Divisor' debe ser divisor común del numerador y del denominador para poder simplificar.
        Si n%d y d%d son 0, el operador && devolverá 0, pero en ese caso debería devolver 1. Por eso uso !().
        Equivalente: if ( (numerador%divisor == 0)     &&     (denominador%divisor == 0)  ) */

        if (!(numerador%divisor) && !(denominador%divisor)){
            //Como el divisor es común, dividimos ambos numerador y denominador entre el divisor común.
            numerador /= divisor;
            denominador /= divisor;
            //La fracción está ahora más simplificada que antes.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eso no es un error. Simplemente, estás intentando entrar dentro de una función **que no es tuya**, sino que forma parte de las librerías del sistema. Salvo que estés depurando el código de dichas librerías. no tienes que entrar ahí para nada. Solo evita entrar en estas funciones.

Comment: ¿Qué función es la que forma parte de las librerías del sistema? ¿`abs()`? Gracias! @Trauma

Comment: Correcto, `abs( )` es una de las *tropezientas* que hay. Por norma, si no es tuya, no intentes entrar.